# Vertx model binding for my Rest API layer

Tags: java, rest, vert.x, vertx3

I'm using Vertx 3, and I'm trying to find a good decoupled module that knows to turn query-string, headers and both content-type and body into a bean?

I know spring does that and various other frameworks as well, but I don't want to introduce a new framework i just want a super fast model binder that will either know to auto bind to a certain method or at least auto bind a certain class so i can invoke my rest method that currently accept one parameter, which is the model.

```
public ResponseBase query(QueryRequest model){ ... }
```

I don't mind adding annotations to the parameters etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current my team use vertx `Json.decodeValue` to turn body (json string) to java class.

```
MyClass body = Json.decodeValue(rc.getBodyAsString(), MyClass.class);
```

to config `Json` to handle unknown properties, I setting

```
Json.mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
```

for your query string, I think it is easy to write a class to convert it to a json string :)

I also catch `DecodeException` on `Json.decodeValue` to re throw a `400` Bad Request error.